# How to implement the intercom/push-to-talk/walkie-talkie feature based on Firebase on Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, intercom

I’m using Firebase as the cloud database and handling authentication for my Android and iOS APPs, it works quite well. Recently I want to add the intercom/push-to-talk/walkie-talkie function to the APPs based on Firebase as well. I have searched on the internet for a while but still am not sure where to start with:

(1) Is it possible to implement the intercom/push-to-talk/walkie-talkie function based on Firebase for both Android and iOS? If yes, is there any tutorial to start with?

(2) If Firebase is not the correct direction, is there any other example/tutorial on the intercom feature for both Android and iOS APPs?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What are you trying to accomplish? What is a *intercom/push-to-talk/walkie-talkie function* and what is preventing you from adding this to your app? Do you have a specific coding issue?

Comment: (1) Sure.
(2) What I’m trying to accomplish is adding an audio-chatting function to my current APP.I understand it’s doable because many APPs are already with this feature. My APPs uses Firebase now, so I want to know if it’s possible to implement audio-chatting based on Firebase.

Comment: (3) I found some APPs which are with the feature I’m looking after describe this function as intercom or push-to-talk or walkie-talkie, I thought it might be more concrete to use the term but I guess it makes some confusion. Anyway, what I’m trying to implement is audio-chatting based on Firebase, and I don’t know how to.
(4) No, I haven’t had any specific issue because I don’t know how to start yet, I tried to find some tutorial or sample code yet  got no luck. I’m quite new to this function so I might miss something while trying to get it started.

Comment: An audio stream is a series of bytes. Assuming for the moment you know how to turn on the Mic and record data it can (Swift) be stored in a Data type and that can be stored directly in Firebase. (FB supports String, Number and Data types). Read and writing is just the same as reading and writing any other type of data. Based on that info it's unclear where you are stuck - is it a Firebase issue where you don't know how to read/write data? Is it a coding issue with audio? That's the clarification that should be added to the question - be aware if the question is too vague, it may be closed.